# What is the fastest case sensitive string comparision in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to join two tables on a char column. The simplest way I use is:

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON (a.text = b.text)
```

This method is quite fast but it the comparison of field is case insensitive. I have tried `STRCMP(.., ..)` and `.. LIKE ..` instead `.. = ..` but both are far to slow. What is the best solution to join two tables on char column with respect to the letter case?

Comment: I have to distinguish between, for example, 'cat' (a noun) and 'Cat' (a proper name, for example last name). I have no choice ;-)

Comment: Could you please post your table definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no possibility to run a benchmark, but have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON (BINARY a.text = BINARY b.text)
```

**EDIT**

*Just as a sidenote: When using the `BINARY` operator both columns `a.text` and `b.text` must use the same **character set** as comparison is done on the byte-level.*

Comment: It works, but it took 8 min 0.73 sec, while the simple comparison only 2 sec. It is strange for me. Is there a solution that is as fast as insensitive comparison?

Comment: The problem is that even if you've indexed both columns correctly, these indexes won't be used as you apply an operator to the column content (same as applying a function). In my opinion you're stuck here if you don't have a chance to modify the database schema at all.

Comment: that's a wrong answer, you should use EXPLAIN first of accepting as the right one.

Comment: @Raffaello What leads to you conclusion that the answer is wrong? `EXPLAIN` in that case will give you information that no index is being used and MySQL does a full table scan to fulfill the join condition. The only way to speed that up is by adding a new column to each of the tables that already contains the `BINARY` value of `text`. These columns can be indexed then.

Comment: Because your answer is not practical. Sorry i was maybe to strict thinking the right answer is to do a refactor on the schema or sort of your juat last comment. I mean you cannot really use your answer in real world scenario except bon nearly empty db.

Answer (score 4):

If that `text` columns are always compared case-sensitively, give them a case sensitive collation in the schema (`VARCHAR BINARY` is one way of doing that) and your original query will work.

Now give them each an index to make the joins fast, if they're not already keys.

Comment: This allows the indexes to be utilized in the query. The accepted answer does not seem to use indexes for me.

Answer (score 2):

don’t join on strings, use surrogate keys instead

Comment: Every entry has its own surrogate key. However, couple entries can have the same text and I need to join using that text. I already have the database and I cannot redesign it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following syntax

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON (a.text = b.text AND BINARY a.text = BINARY b.text)
```

The first join condition will preserve the query plan and therefore the response time, and the second one will deal with the sensitivity issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your tables using certain character sets and collations (f.e. latin1_bin) that are case sensitive. Just look at the create table syntax. in this case the = operator should be as fast as on standard settings (like f.e. latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check indexes on these columns. This join takes fractions of a second on thousands of rows in both tables, provided that the fields are indexed properly.

Second, make sure you use same collations on both table. If you don't, specify the collation for the table column you want to be leading in the join.

Note that collation conversion makes condition not sargable and the indexes not usable. If you want case sensitive comparison to be fast, make sure your collation is set to `binary` (like `UTF8_BIN`) in both fields.